# How can I add new row to database with values stored in ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

So I have two ObservableCollections:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Student> studentslist
ObservableCollection<Subject> subjectslist
```

and I'm passing them to class where I have set up whole communication with sql database.

studentslist contains values passed by:

```cs
StudentsList.Add(new Student { IdStudent = newStudentId, Name = NameBox.Text, Surname = SurnameBox.Text, Index = IndexBox.Text })
```

subjectlist contains values from checked checkboxes in my listbox (I'm still not sure if this is correct):

```cs
var selectedSubjects = SubjectList.Where(subjects => subjects.IsChecked == true);
var selectedSubjectsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Subject>(selectedSubjects);
```

and this is my Subject class:

```cs
public class Subject
    {
        public int IdSubject{ get; set; }
        public string subject{ get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{subject}";
        }
    }
```

Now in my class, responsible for connection with sql data base, I've created method which grabs both of this collections and based on their values I would like to create new record in database:

```cs
public void addRecord(ObservableCollection<Student> studentslist, ObservableCollection<Przedmiot> subjectslist)
        {
            OpenConection();
            //...
            CloseConnection();
        }
```

In database I have Student table:

```
Student(IdStudent, FirstName, LastName, IndexNumber)
```

and Subject table:

```
Subject(IdSubject, Name)
```

And as far as I can read data from my data base, I don't know how in correct way pass these values to corresponding values in data base.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need EntityFramework or other ORM to make CRUD operations

Comment: Inserting ID of a student is never a good idea! Let SQL handle that. The table needs to have that field set to autoincrement and NOT NULL. I noticed that you either handle the logic in code behind or you pass UI elements to the ViewModel, which is bad practise in both cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do this kind of thing using stored procedures to minimise the amount of T-SQL code in the app.

An example would be:

```
public static void InsertSubject(Przedmiot subject)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertSubject", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdSubject", subject.IdSubject));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", subject.subject));

            conn.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

You would then have a stored procedure with the same signature to perform the `INSERT`, i.e.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertSubject
    @IdSubject int
    , @Name varchar(50)
AS

...

GO
```

If you want to pass in the entire collection you could implement a `foreach` loop in the above example.

Personally I like to call these methods once per insert and have it as an `int` returning method (for example) so I can pass some data out, e.g., the ID of the inserted row.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to use it but unfortunately I get an error: **SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[InsertStudent] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[apbd.Student].** I've even created new topic about it because I cannot find a solution which would work for me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602595/procedure-not-working-because-of-unresolved-reference-to-object)

Comment: I've added an answer to that question which will hopefully help.

Comment: I've resolved the problem and now your solution works perfectly :) Thank you for your help.